# How to set a clickListener from Fragment on a button belonging to the Activity?

Tags: android, event-handling

The structure of my application is just an `Activity` which shows `Fragment` one at a time. The layout of the activity is defined by an xml file where it's present a `FloatingActionButton`. Fragments should intercept click events on the button, but the `onClick()` is never called.

Activity xml layout:

```
...

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/fab"
   android:visibility="visible"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

...
```

Fragment class:

```
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        adapterCity = new AdapterCity(getContext(), 0, Main.cities);
        setListAdapter(adapterCity);
        colorAccent = getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMap();
            }
        });
        fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bubble_chart_black_24dp));
    }

    ...
```

It seems that UI events from the activity aren't propagated to the attacched fragments. What is happening here? How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Use static methods suppose if different fragments has different fab actions then it will eaiser to handle these actions in fragments

Answer (score 1):

This is **not a good practice**. Fragments should not know directly about hosting activity nor should they access the views from them. This can be done by having your activity implement a custom interface which has some methods in it, for example `myMethod()`, and then calling `getActivity()` and typecasting it to the interface and the calling the method, like this:

```
((MyInterface)getActivity()).myMethod();
```

Now for your particular case, I'd suggest that you pass some kind of a variable which will differ in each of the fragments and based on that in you Activity's implementation of `myMethod()` set different `onClickListeners` to your `FloatingActionButton`.